# Set-ADFSProperties "EnableExtranetLockout" error in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, windows-server-2008-r2, adfs2.0, lockout

I am implementing SSO using ADFS 2.0. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. Now, I want to restrict the number of attempts that a user gets to log on, to 3. I came across [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486806.aspx) which suggested me to set up the following three parameters:

- EnableExtranetLockout
- ExtranetLockoutThreshold
- ExtranetObservationWindow

I referred [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-powershell-basics%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to register and add ADFS 2.0 snap-in to windows powershell.

However, when I query Get-ADFSProperties, I don't get the three properties I listed above. [image]

Also quite understandably, I get the following error when I execute this command:
 ***Set-AdfsProperties -EnableExtranetLockout $true -ExtranetLockoutThreshold 15 -ExtranetObservationWindow ( new-timespan -Minutes 30 )***
 [image]

Error message is:

```
Set-ADFSProperties : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnableExtranetLockout'.
```

At line:1 char:42

```
Set-AdfsProperties -EnableExtranetLockout <<<<  $true -ExtranetLockoutThreshold 15 -ExtranetObservationWindow ( new-timespan -Minutes 30 ) 
CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADFSProperties], ParameterBindingException 
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceProperties Command
```

This error has been mentioned [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/05/05/enabling-adfs-2012-r2-extranet-lockout-protection.aspx) but that doesn't apply in my case cause the properties aren't getting listed in the first place!

I would appreciate any help or suggestion wrt the same.

Thanks!

Comment: According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486806.aspx, this feature works only for AD FS in Windows Server 2012 R2, which I thought I had. I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and I don't know how to implement this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

you need to upgrade to ADFS 2012 R2.  The extranet account lockout feature is not present in any builds prior to that.

Cheers,
Rhoderick 
[Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/rmilne)